# bootstrap 3 container size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to working with Bootstrap 3 . I made a container 12 columns with `width: 960px;`. Then I noticed the container size changed to `width: 1110px`. Can anyone tell me what the issue is? I just want a fixed container with width of 960px;

Please check it [here](http://mohammadsamy.com/Goejaza/index.html)

I found the css :

```
.col-lg-12 {
    margin-left: 0;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: how do I change the width of the container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884102/bootstrap-how-do-i-change-the-width-of-the-container)

Comment: Read about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive). Look at the example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/). Get all your css [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css)

Comment: @Mohamed Samy Are you on any of these **Sass** or **LESS** ?

Answer (score 1):

modify this CSS properties from bootstrap.css

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px; }
  .container:before, .container:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  .container:after {
    clear: both; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
      width: 732px; } }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
      width: 952px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
      width: 1152px; } }
```

**Remove**

```
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
      width: 1152px; }
```

**Update**

```
  @media (min-width: 990px) {
    .container {
      width: 950px; } }
```

Please comment below if anything wrong while apply this code

Comment: Above code to look for does not exist in bootstrap 3.1

Comment: `.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px; }
  .container:before, .container:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  .container:after {
    clear: both; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
      width: 732px; } }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
      width: 952px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
      width: 1152px; } }`

Comment: also this is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057380/bootstrap-3-how-to-set-default-grid-to-960px-width

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting: if you are using **less** or **sass** with Bootstrap, changing the size of the containers is as easy as changing one variable. In Bootstrap 3 (3.3.5 to be precise) their container settings in the `variables.less` file look like this:

```
//== Container sizes
//
//## Define the maximum width of `.container` for different screen sizes.

// Small screen / tablet
@container-tablet:             (720px + @grid-gutter-width);
//** For `@screen-sm-min` and up.
@container-sm:                 @container-tablet;

// Medium screen / desktop
@container-desktop:            (940px + @grid-gutter-width);
//** For `@screen-md-min` and up.
@container-md:                 @container-desktop;

// Large screen / wide desktop
@container-large-desktop:      (1140px + @grid-gutter-width);
//** For `@screen-lg-min` and up.
@container-lg:                 @container-large-desktop;
```

(see [bootstrap's github repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/less/variables.less#L335-L352))

So to adapt the size of `.container` for large screens, simply overwrite the variable `@container-large-desktop` by adding it to your own `variables.less`-file:

```
@container-large-desktop: ((930px + @grid-gutter-width));
```

(`@grid-gutter-witdh` is set to `30px` on default, so the above will lead to having a 960px container)